# Postgres triggers and no-op updates

Tags: postgresql, triggers, materialized-views

On Postgres 9.5 I've implemented an eager materialised view with upsert triggers on `UPDATE` (I need incremental updating, and the built-in materialised views don't support that), this seems to work well.

But I also have the need to initialise these tables on existing DBs, and sometimes to truncate and rebuild them; I need the built-in `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VTEW`.  I could duplicate the upsert queries in the triggers, modifying the trigger-specific code, but I don't like duplicate code.

I find that running a no-op `UPDATE` on the trigger's source table(s)

```
UPDATE source_table SET id = id;
```

does trigger my triggers, and so updates the view as required.

I've not come across this sort of "touch" query before, and worry that that it might be fragile -- Postgres happens to behave like this now, but it's not standard and will change in 9.6.   A justified worry?

Comment: This *idle* update in no way differs from any other *real* update. It doesn't depend on the Postgres version and doesn't seem it would change in future.

Comment: The behavior *won't change* precisely because that would break use cases like this.